# Screen is unreadable on fresh install with GTX 660 TI

Tags: graphics, display-resolution

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 The screen looks as if it is in 320 x 240 and then upscaled to 1920x1080

My monitor tells me `suggested resolution 1920x 1080`. So my guess is that the monitor is doing some upscaling

My graphics card is a GTX 660 TI

Can anyone help me get the screen to a readable state?

Answer (score 2):

Actually I've solved it - the proprietary driver was installed. What was screwing it up was that I had a second monitor of a different resolution plugged into an hdmi port on the same card. I disconnected the second monitor, rebooted and got a proper display. Reconnected the second monitor and let Ubuntu detect it normally and all is now well

Answer (score 1):

You need to install  a proprietary Nvidia driver. The best solution for this card is to do it this way. Run in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

Then reboot.

Comment: Actually I've solved it - the proprietary driver was installed. What was screwing it up was that I had a second monitor of a different resolution plugged into an hdmi port on the same card.  I disconnected the second monitor, rebooted and got a proper display.  Reconnected the second monitor and let Ubuntu detect it normally and all is now well.

Comment: @Lawrence: if that's the answer, please add it as an answer. Remove the word "Solved" from your question and mark your answer as accepted as soon as you can. That's the correct way to mark a question as solved here on AskUbuntu.